# Return false in $.each inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am iterating through two arrays by using $.each inside $.each , and i want to return false for the first $.each when an event in the second $.each happens what should i do

```
$.each(dbFields, function(index, valuedb) {
    $.each(editFields, function(index, value2) {
        if ((valuedb.region == value2.regionField) && (valuedb.dbtype == value2.typeField)) {
            $('#' + value2.idField).attr('id', valuedb.dbid) ; 
            $('#' + valuedb.dbid).attr('elementid', valuedb.dbid) ;                  
            console.log('Match found between ' + value2.idField + ' and '+valuedb.dbid);
            return false; //return false for the first $.each
        }
        else {
            return true ; //return truefor the first $.each
        }      
    });
});
```

Now when the event return false happens, it returns false for the second $.each

Comment: That `else` block isn't necessary.  Returning `true` just continues the default behavior of `each()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a flag so that your outer loop knows to return false:

```
$.each(dbFields, function(index, valuedb) {
    var flag = true; // <=============

    $.each(editFields, function(index, value2) {
        if ((valuedb.region == value2.regionField) && (valuedb.dbtype == value2.typeField)) {

            $('#' + value2.idField).attr('id', valuedb.dbid);
            $('#' + valuedb.dbid).attr('elementid', valuedb.dbid);
            console.log('Match found between ' + value2.idField + ' and ' + valuedb.dbid);
            flag = false; // <=============
            return false; //return false for the first $.each

        } /* You don't need this ==============> else {

            return true; //return truefor the first $.each
        } */

    });

    return flag;  // <=============
});
```

That returns `true` if you don't ever see the condition, which is fine; `$.each` ignores all return values except `false`.

Comment: it works thanks, i don't know how i didn't think about a simple solution like this, thanks mate.